# Question on collection of open covers for compact sets

Tags: general-topology

This is in Baby Rudin. I am reading a proof that compact subsets of metric spaces are closed. In the proof the author takes the open cover $\{W_q : q \in K\}$ where $W_q$ is some open neighborhood of $q$ and $K$ is the compact set. My question is that an open cover was defined to be a collection of open subsets $\{G_{\alpha}\}$ where the open sets are indexed by some $\alpha.$ Does the fact that the collection is indexed imply that we can only have countably many open sets? If so, aren't we assuming that there are only countably many points inside our compact set and hence might not be a valid open cover?

Comment: Think about this open cover of $\mathbb R$: $\mathscr{A}=\{ (x-1,x+1)\}_{x\in\mathbb R}$

Comment: This proof itself is a counterexample , as the $W_q$ are indexed by points $q$ , of which there probably uncountably many. Any set can be an index set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Does the fact that the collection is indexed imply that we can only have countably many open sets ?"

Not at all ! We can define a family indexed by *any* set, including uncountable ones. Set-theoretically, a family $(G_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ of open subsets of $K$ is just a map $A\to \{\text{open subsets of }K\}$ and it does not depend on the cardinality of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the collection is indexed means that we can identify each element of the collection by knowing its index.  More specifically, if $A$ is the index set, then there is a function $\iota : A \to \{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ which takes an index as input and returns the corresponding set as output; that is
$$ \iota(\alpha) = G_{\alpha}.$$
For example, we can define an interval $I_x$ by setting
$$ I_x := (x,x+1).$$
The collection $\{I_x\}_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ indexed by the uncountable set $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

This proof shows why we need arbitary covers. The indexing is irrelevant but makes the notation easier, and clearer in proofs. Here we pick $W_q$ (of a point $q\in K$) disjoint from some neighbourhood $U_q$ of some $x \notin K$. We heavily use the axiom of choice to do this for all $q \in K$ simultaneously, and because we use the same indexing set $K$, in the rest of the proof we have a finite subcover, of which we know the indices, and then we use those $U_q$ with the same indices.

The property that every **countable** open cover has a finite subcover is called "countably compact" and for general spaces, it's a weaker property.

An index-free to state compactness for a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$:

$$\forall \mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{T}: (\bigcup \mathcal{U} = X) \implies (\exists \mathcal{U}' \subseteq \mathcal{U}: \mathcal{U'} \text{finite and } \bigcup \mathcal{U'} = X)$$

Comment: Thanks! Although, what is meant by arbitrary covers? A collection of open sets we can choose in any way?

Comment: @ntntnt yes indeed, any collection of open sets such that each point of the set is in at least one of them ( every point is "covered").